# Resize an image to a bitmap in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I get an image capture from the camera, it has a size of 1440x1080. But I use a bitmap to save it, its size is 1080x720.

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.lastIndex)
```

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Use bitmap factory to convert it into desire one

Comment: can you tell me more?

Comment: @minhduc Please provide more of your relevant code.

Comment: i fixed it, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code.

```
val b =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.lastIndex)
var bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 720, 1080, false)
```